# Style the first column of a table differently if there is no <thead>

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is the markup I'm trying to style:

```
  <h2>Table with no header</h2>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First column - bold</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First column - bold</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h2>Table with a header</h2>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>First column - not bold</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First column - not bold</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: `!important` doesn't *seem* to be necessary(?):  https://jsfiddle.net/91e9ukf9/

Comment: Rick is correct. `thead + tbody td:first-child` is *more* specific than `td:first-child`, and so it will take precedent without the use of `!important`.

Comment: Doh! I've just removed the `!important` and it all looks perfect. Thanks @RickHitchcock and @Santi. Not sure what I did there... I guess I already have my answer then. I'll reword my question and add an answer in case it's useful to anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this, where you use the direct child selector `>`, `first-child` and `:not()`

```
table > *:first-child:not(thead) td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Sample

```css
table > *:first-child:not(thead) td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h2>Table with no header</h2>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First column - bold</td>
      <td>Second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First column - bold</td>
      <td>Second column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Table with a header</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First column - not bold</td>
      <td>Second column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First column - not bold</td>
      <td>Second column</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to achieve the desired look using the following CSS:

```
  td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  thead + tbody td:first-child {
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
```